# Repo via reposync creates Packages dir

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, repository

I am using `/usr/bin/reposync --arch=x86_64 --repoid=rhel-6-server-rpms --download_path=/data/repos --plugins --downloadcomps`

It creates `/data/repos/rhel-6-server-rpms` and downloads the packages in `/data/repos/rhel-6-server-rpms/Packages`. I don't like that last part: **Packages**, because I have to put /Packages behind the baseurl of my repo conf.

What can I do? I didn't find an option in reposync to define this. Moving after download won't be a good idea (I think), because reposync will then download everything again each night.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should proceed with updating your Yum repo configuration files to carry the `Packages` part.

But, if you're adamant about doing this, change the `Packages` directory into a symbolic link.

```
mv -i /data/repos/rhel-6-server-rpms/Packages/* /data/repos/rhel-6-server-rpms
ln -s /data/repos/rhel-6-server-rpms/ /data/repos/rhel-6-server-rpms/Packages
```

The next time you run `reposync`, it will maintain the symbolic link.

Comment: In my case, I needed to translate the path components from `6repo` to  `repo/6/x86_64/`, and your suggestion about links worked perfectly